# How to use one table component multiple times with different el and data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Bootstrap-vue table component for my project:

```
<b-table><b-table>
```

Here I want to use the same component multiple times and show different data, As I'm using `axios.get('url')` to display the API response on table:

```js
methods: {
    myProvider() {
      this.isBusy = true
      axios.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
        this.items = response.data
        console.log(items)
        this.isBusy = false
        return (items)
      }).catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
        this.isBusy = false
        return {}
      })
    },
```

How do the declare the el and pass the data to the table, with 3 different API response.

As example:

```
<b-table id="data1" :get="1api"></b-table>
<b-table id="data2" :get="api2"></b-table>
<b-table id="data3" :get="api3"></b-table>
```

Comment: Paste the `axios.get('url')` whole code. You are probably going to use a [`v-for`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

Comment: methods: {
    myProvider () {
      this.isBusy = true
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {
          this.items = response.data
          console.log(items)
          this.isBusy = false
          return (items)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
          this.isBusy = false
          return {}
        })
},

Comment: You shouldn't paste it in comments. I pasted your code in your question. Please double check if I pasted it right.

Comment: Also, it is not clear, what do you mean, for example,  `data2` and `api2` are? Elements from the `this.item` array?

Comment: show your html and js please not just the js